# Append feature frequency to existing list

Tags: python, list, loops, nltk

I am looking for an fairly efficient way to append the frequency of a feature in a list each item in that list.

For example, given this list:

```
[['syme', 4, 2], ['said', 4, 2], ['the', 3, 5]]
```

I would like to append to it **the frequency with which the second two items occur in the list**.  In the list above, this would look something like this:

```
[['syme', 4, 2, 2], ['said', 4, 2, 2], ['the', 3, 5, 1]]
```

Where the third number represents **how frequently the second two numbers occur as the second two items in the lists**.  (for example, [4, 2] appears twice as the second two numbers and [3,5] appears once so the first two lists would append a 2 at the end and the third list would append a 1.)

The actual list may have several hundred thousand items so both efficiency AND readable code are both valued here and I would like to maintain the current order of the list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Have you actually discovered a performance problem, e.g. through profiling?

Comment: Can you please clarify: how is the new item in the list derived from the other items?

Comment: Does order matter for the two items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most performant method is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the counts based on pairs

```
counts = Counter(tuple(item[1:]) for item in lst)
```

then update the list accordingly:

```
for item in lst:
    item.append(counts[tuple(item[1:])])
```

If the order of the two items doesn't matter, wrap `item[1:]` with `sorted(...)` when creating `counts` and updating `lst`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `collections.Counter` class:

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = [['syme', 4, 2], ['said', 4, 2], ['the', 3, 5]]
counts = Counter([(x[1],x[2],) for x in my_list])

for sub_list in my_list:
    sub_list.append(counts[(sub_list[1], sub_list[2])])
```

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter:

```
import collections
collections.Counter(frozenset((i[1], i[2]))


a_list = [['syme', 4, 2], ['said', 4, 2], ['the', 3, 5]]

counts = Counter(frozenset(l[1], l[2]) for x in a_list)

for l in a_list:
    l.append(counts[frozenset(l[1], l[2])])
```